# BUG on boost spirit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to migrate my code from VSC++ 6 to VSC++ 2008 express edition and from Intel compiler to Microsoft compiler. Everything were easy to migrate except that I'm receiving this errors now:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Base, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>DefaultScriptReader.cpp
1>Warning: This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp
1>Warning: This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/classic_dynamic.hpp
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(53) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::lazy_parser<ActorT>' being compiled
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(33) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(34) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(40) : error C2065: 'actor_result_t' : undeclared identifier
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::lazy_parser<ActorT>::result<ScannerT>' being compiled
1>Warning: This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/phoenix1.hpp
1>Warning: This header is deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/classic_grammar_def.hpp
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(104) : error C2039: 'nil_t' : is not a member of 'boost::phoenix'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(112) : error C2039: 'nil_t' : is not a member of 'boost::phoenix'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(299) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::grammar_def<T,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>' being compiled
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(180) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(187) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(297) : error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(298) : error C2760: syntax error : expected '{' not ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(299) : fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(54)' was matched
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Desenvolvimento\DFF\VC9\Base\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Base - 17 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How you can see, the MS Compiler shows syntax errors on boost library. 
I found on boost site that this compiler, version 9, is compatible to the library. 
So, what is going on to my code?

The code with deprecated parts fixed:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Base, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>DefaultScriptReader.cpp
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(53) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::classic::lazy_parser<ActorT>' being compiled
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(33) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(34) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(40) : error C2065: 'actor_result_t' : undeclared identifier
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/dynamic/lazy.hpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::classic::lazy_parser<ActorT>::result<ScannerT>' being compiled
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(104) : error C2039: 'nil_t' : is not a member of 'boost::phoenix'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(112) : error C2039: 'nil_t' : is not a member of 'boost::phoenix'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(180) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>        c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(299) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::classic::grammar_def<T,T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>' being compiled
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(180) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(187) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(277) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(297) : error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(298) : error C2760: syntax error : expected '{' not ';'
1>c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(299) : fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'c:\Desenvolvimento\dff_dependencies_windows\include\boost/spirit/home/classic/utility/grammar_def.hpp(56)' was matched
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Desenvolvimento\DFF\VC9\Base\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Base - 17 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks
Leandro Lima

Comment: Did you see the "deprecated" warning messages?

Comment: yeah! But I change to the indicated and anything different ocurrs

Comment: ok, so you've changed your code, can you add the current error messages to your question now

Comment: That is it...the code with deprecated parts fixed

Comment: What's in DefaultScriptReader.cpp at the top (with the includes and above)

Comment: can you repoduce the error with a cut-down code excerpt which you could then post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved just including phoenix1. The old version of phoenix.